# SSIS package runs slow on server but fine on dev machine

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, odbc, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS package that moves data from SQL server to a Postgres 9.5 database. I'm using the latest Postgres ODBC drivers to connect to the postgres server. The bulk of the operations are inserts and updates and upserts. When I run this package from my development machine (Win 10 64-bit) in Visual Studio 2012 it's quite speedy. It can transfer about 80k rows in around 40 seconds.

When I deploy it to the server (an SQL Server 2012 instance) and run it using SQL management studio it executes painfully slow. It took around 20 seconds to transfer less than 10 rows, and takes forever to work on the full data set. I never let if finish because it just takes too long.

Both my development machine and the server have the exact same postgres driver installed and identically configured ODBC sources.

Edit: I should also note that I have other packages deployed to that server that run just fine, though these packages don't touch postgres or use ODBC for anything.

Comment: Are you using the same databases from local and server? if not, maybe server is busy or the table on server is huge but your development table is tiny.

Comment: Is it the same table in postgres that you are working with from your local and on the server?  Could you provide an image of the dataflow that is running slowly?

Comment: Check for ODBC and/or driver tracing/logging.

Comment: FLICKER & Mark, it's the same DB and tables on both development and the test server.

TallTed could you elaborate? Where do I find those and what should I be looking for?

Comment: Start by looking in the ODBC Administrator a/k/a Data Sources control panel, Tracing tab.  Make sure this is disabled.  Also look in your DSN setup, and make sure there is no tracing/logging enabled there.

Answer (score 0):

If all else is equal:

- Same drivers
- Same configurations - ODBC (i.e. ssl, same boxes ticked), package parameters
- Same tables - with same amount of data in them and indexes
- Same bit-ness (64x)

I would look towards resource differences.  I.e.

- is the IO the same.  Assuming this is writing to the same database (and files), then this should not be an issue.
- Memory - is the ram constrained on the dev instance?  If the dataflow has large buffers this could really slow things down.
- CPU - is the dev server more limited than your dev machine
- Network - is the dev server sitting in a different subnet with differing QoS.  I would guess this is not an issue since other packages are not affected.  Unless there is something weird when connecting to Postgres.

Another way to zero in on the issue would be to run different versions of the package, stripping out parts of the dataflow.  i.e. remove the odbc / ado.net destination  and run the package.  If it finishes quickly, you know the issue is there.  If it is still slow, keep going upstream until you've identified the component that's slow.

Lastly, I would consider using psql over odbc.  psql is a postgres utility, like SQL's bcp, which would allow you to bulk copy data to postgres.  The odbc driver will only allow row by row inserts which tend to be sluggish.  Writing the data to a tab delimited file and then using psql to bulk copy the data into postgres is actually significantly faster (80k rows might take 5s all told).